# How to disable the default context menu for mouse right button in WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have the following event handler:

```
private void rtb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        // Get the nearest TextPointer to the mouse position. 
        TextPointer location = rtb.GetPositionFromPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(rtb), true);

        // Get the nearest word using this TextPointer. 
        TextRange word = GetWordRange(location);

        // Display the word. 
        tb.Text = word.Text;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This is wired to the PreviewMouseDown event of a RichTextBox.  This event fires and the above method is invoked, and the word under the cursor is displayed in a separate TextBox (called tb).

The problem is that, afterwards the default context menu (containing cut/copy/paste options) for the mouse right button click event is also displayed.  Setting the Handled property to true does not seem to help.  How can I have this context menu disabled?

EDIT: Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="rtbTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,127,0,0" Name="rtb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="483" PreviewMouseDown="rtb_MouseDown" />
        <TextBox Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,24,0,0" Name="tb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,56,0,0" Name="btn1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btn1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please add the xaml code as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`null` it:

```
<RichTextBox ContextMenu="{x:Null}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks.  What I don't understand is: Doesn't this disable *all* context menus for RichTextBox?  Also, is this how it should be done, or is this a brute force solution?

Comment: @Sabuncu: There is more than one context menu? If you want another context menu just don't make it null but set it to that context menu you want, there is nothing remotely brute about this.

Comment: The context menu that has cut/copy/paste is displayed because some event handler upstream gets triggered.  Why is this even if I am setting Handled to true in my event handler code?

Comment: @Sabuncu: You are handling a different event, you stopping the event going down (`PreviewMouseDown`) does not stop the event comming up (`MouseDown`), also i'd assume that the `ContextMenu` uses `MouseUp`. Or possibly the right button variants..

Comment: Very frustrating that this doesn't work in a data template, for some bizarre reason. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b4e5caa3-d134-4bb3-8175-7e1468b31698/how-to-disable-contextmenu-in-textbox-in-a-datatemplate?forum=wpf